# make big process on graph with python parallelised

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, parallel-processing

i'm working on graphs and big dataset of complex network's. i run SIR algorithm on them with ndlib library.
but each iteration takes something like 1Sec and it make code takes 10-12 h to complete . 
i was wondering is there any way to make it parallelised ? 
the code is like down bellow

this line of the code is core :

```
sir = model.infected_SIR_MODEL(it, infectionList, False)
```

is there any simple method to make it run on multi thread or parallelised ?

```
count = 500
for i in numpy.arange(1, count, 1):

    for it in model.get_nodes():

        sir = model.infected_SIR_MODEL(it, infectionList, False)
```

each iteration :

```
 for u in self.graph.nodes():

            u_status = self.status[u]
            eventp = np.random.random_sample()
            neighbors = self.graph.neighbors(u)
            if isinstance(self.graph, nx.DiGraph):
                neighbors = self.graph.predecessors(u)

            if u_status == 0:
                infected_neighbors = len([v for v in neighbors if self.status[v] == 1])
                if eventp < self.BetaList[u] * infected_neighbors:
                    actual_status[u] = 1
            elif u_status == 1:
                if eventp < self.params['model']['gamma']:
                    actual_status[u] = 2
```

Comment: That depends - are the iterations independent? Is only one of them independent - which one? Or does the `model` change during iterations?

Comment: there is a for and in it on each node process happen.. i think they are independent. one by one @MarekSchwarz

Comment: model is static

Comment: The question is If, during the processing, is the `model` changed somehow..? Or if you could run `i=10` independently of `i=100`. OK..

Comment: And the `infectionList` is also static?

Comment: yes infectionList is static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if the iterations are independent, then I don't see the point of iteration over `count=500`. Either way the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) library might be of interest to you.

I've prepared 2 stub solutions (i.e. alter to your exact needs). 
The first expects that every input is static (the changes in solutions as far as I understand the OP's question raise from the random state generation inside each iteration). With the second, you can update the input data between iterations of `i`. I've not tried the code as I don't have the `model` so it might not work directly.

```
import multiprocessing as mp


# if everything is independent (eg. "infectionList" is static and does not change during the iterations)

def worker(model, infectionList):
    sirs = []
    for it in model.get_nodes():
        sir = model.infected_SIR_MODEL(it, infectionList, False)
        sirs.append(sir)
    return sirs

count = 500
infectionList = []
model = "YOUR MODEL INSTANCE"

data = [(model, infectionList) for _ in range(1, count+1)]
with mp.Pool() as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(worker, data)
```

The second proposed solution if "infectionList" or something else gets updated in each iteration of "i":

```
def worker2(model, it, infectionList):
    sir = model.infected_SIR_MODEL(it, infectionList, False)
    return sir

with mp.Pool() as pool:
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        data = [(model, it, infectionList) for it in model.get_nodes()]
        results = pool.starmap(worker2, data)

        # process results, update something go to next iteration....
```

Edit: Updated the answer to separate proposals more clearly.

Comment: thanks for responding. an Explanation : here model is a complex Graph and i run "infected_SIR_MODEL" on each node . then what is this line of code mean : "data = [(model, infectionList) for _ in range(1, count+1)]" ??

Comment: i set count on 10 . i got 3 line of result exactly like each other . 3 other again like each . 2 other lines are  new result's but actually there is 3 bunch of res . why answers are like this?

Comment: The `data = [(model, infectionList) for _ in range(1, count+1)]` does following: Make a list of tuples (which are input to `worker`) from 1 to `count` + 1. As far as I understand your `infected_SIR_MODEL` - you are generating some random state inside the function. That might cause the differences. The multiprocessing does nothing with your code.

Comment: nice work thanks. infected_SIR_MODEL() method uses probability in it self. does multiprocessing make something that maybe some of results be exactly like  together?

Comment: You'll have to seed the rng generator inside the function. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915177/same-output-in-different-workers-in-multiprocessing and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209078/using-python-multiprocessing-with-different-random-seed-for-each-process