# Python random.choice always selects first value

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
AUDIO_FILES = [
    os.path.join(settings.AUDIO_FILES_DIR, "1.mp3"),
    os.path.join(settings.AUDIO_FILES_DIR, "2.mp3"),
    os.path.join(settings.AUDIO_FILES_DIR, "3.mp3"),
    os.path.join(settings.AUDIO_FILES_DIR, "4.mp3"),
    os.path.join(settings.AUDIO_FILES_DIR, "5.mp3"),
]

def _get_audio_clip():
    audio_file = random.choice(AUDIO_FILES)
    audio_clip = AudioFileClip(audio_file)
    return audio_clip

_get_audio_clip()
```

Can anyone point out why random.choice always returns first value of the list in this piece of code?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't, how many tries did you do ? Print out the result from `choice` you'll see ;)

Comment: It does time after time after time. There is something wrong I must be doing butot selects first value every single time.

Comment: What do you mean does not even make any choice? random.choice is choosing one file.

Comment: Why downvote this?

Comment: Have you used import random? You need this for random.choice() to work

Comment: Yes I've imported random. This is part of a 4000 line file Whole of which I cannot post here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914240/multiprocessing-pool-seems-to-work-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu) answered my question. Quoting the answer:

> What happens is that on Unix every worker process inherits the same state of the random number generator from the parent process. This is why they generate identical pseudo-random sequences.

Using random.seed() in the worker process solved the problem.