# Python multiprocessing gets stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I am pretty new to Python and totally new to multiprocessing, I found a few tutorials online to help me understand the multiprocessing package.

My code has a set of differential equations using RungeKutta4 method and I need to run tons of calculations with different starting conditions.

The code itself works but without multiprocessing it takes long to finish and I thought it might be ideal to use parallelization because the calculations are independent....

I am using Anaconda as IDE btw..

So I used

```
import multiprocessing as mp
iterations = np.arange(start,end,step)
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())                           # Step 1: Init multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(rungeKutta4, [k for k in iterations]) # Step 2: apply pool map              
pool.close()                                             # Step 3: close
```

When I run it in Anaconda I dont get an error, it starts calculating but it never stops....
Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance for help...

Best

EDIT: I added the whole code here...

```
# Python program to implement Runge Kutta method 
# Markus Schmid
# 2020 Appalachian State University
# jupyter nbconvert --to python FILENAME.ipynb

# y" + 2*beta*y' + w0*sin(y) = A + B*cos(w*t)
# Import used libraries
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
import multiprocessing as mp
print("Number of processors: ", mp.cpu_count())
# list for time (x axis) and result (y axis)
result = []
w0 = 10                  # undamped angular frequency of the oscillator
beta = 1
B = 1
A = 0
B = 10
w = 4
theta_init = 0
theta_end = 20
theta_step = 0.1

# initial conditions
t0 = 0
y0 = 0
z0 = 0
t_final = 20                   # final time
h = 0.01                    # fixed step size
n = (int)((t_final - t0)/h)   # datapoints per RK4 iteration

# define functions
def funcf(t, y, z): 
    return (z)
def funcg(t, y, z): 
    return (A+B*math.cos(w*t) - 2*beta*z - w0*math.sin(y))

# Finds value of y for a given x using step size h 
# and initial value y0 at x0. 
def rungeKutta4(y): 
    # Count number of iterations using step size or 
    # step height h 
    t = t0
    z = z0
    n = (int)((t_final - t)/h)  
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
        # Apply Runge Kutta to find next value of y
        k1 = h * funcf(t, y, z) 
        l1 = h * funcg(t, y, z)  

        k2 = h * funcf(t + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k1, z + 0.5 * l1) 
        l2 = h * funcg(t + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k1, z + 0.5 * l1)  

        k3 = h * funcf(t + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k2, z + 0.5 * l2) 
        l3 = h * funcg(t + 0.5 * h, y + 0.5 * k2, z + 0.5 * l2) 

        k4 = h * funcf(t + h, y + k3, z + l3) 
        l4 = h * funcg(t + h, y + k3, z + l3) 

        # Update next value of y 
        y = y + (1.0 / 6.0)*(k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) 
        z = z + (1.0 / 6.0)*(l1 + 2 * l2 + 2 * l3 + l4) 

        #result.append(y)                
        t = t + h # Update next value of t
    return y 

iterations = np.arange(theta_init,theta_end+theta_step,theta_step)   # number iterations for omega sweep

start_time = time.time()
#for k in iterations:     # for serial calculation
#            rungeKutta4(k)
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) # Step 1: Init multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(rungeKutta4, [k for k in iterations]) # Step 2: apply pool map        
end_time = time.time()            
pool.close()  # Step 3: close
print ("The program took", end_time - start_time, "s to run")

#table = np.array(result).reshape(len(iterations),n)   # rearrange array, 1 row is const. theta0
timer = np.arange(t0,t_final,h) # time array
```

Comment: You should post the ```rangeKutta4``` function as well as the values of ```start, end, step```.

Comment: IDE's can interact with Python in unexpected ways. There are several mentions of `multiprocessing` misbehaving in IDE's on stackoverflow. Therefore it is probably best to test your script by directly calling Python from a shell (`cmd.exe` on ms-windows).

Comment: I tried running it without Anaconda ..
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: If you want to speed up your code further, use a method with adaptive step size, like RKF or DoPri. The `scipy` solvers are, per hearsay, not very suitable for parallel computing, so you would have to implement your own routine. Does `multiprocessing` do JIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial comment:

> IDE's can interact with Python in unexpected ways. There are several mentions of multiprocessing misbehaving in IDE's on stackoverflow. Therefore it is probably best to test your script by directly calling Python from a shell (cmd.exe on ms-windows).

You replied:

> RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

For `multiprocessing` to work well on ms-windows, you have to be able to import the code in your script *without side effects such as starting a new process*.

This means that you have to put your everything except imports and function/class definitions inside a main block, like in this exemple inspired by the documentation:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def foo():
    print('hello')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target=foo)
    p.start()
```

Basically, ms-windows lacks the pretty nifty `fork()` system call that exists on UNIX-like systems.
So the Python developers had to come up with a clever hack to make `multiprocessing` work on ms-windows.
See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361032/1219295) for the gory details.

**Edit** On ms-windows it seems that it is also necessary to put the worker function in its own file and import it. See e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac).

Comment: thank you very much that helped a lot!! 
I have it working on the terminal but not on Anaconda but it's a start.. 
I tried it with the needed resolution and it cut the time to 1/4 

Next step is to use Anaconda and rework my loop (I need all calculations not only the last one and in the right order but 1 problem at a time.. )

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you mean Jupyter notebooks? If so, you should be aware that this is also known to not work well with `multiprocessing` on ms-windows without some extra steps. See [(1)](https://medium.com/@grvsinghal/speed-up-your-python-code-using-multiprocessing-on-windows-and-jupyter-or-ipython-2714b49d6fac), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641475/multiprocessing-working-in-python-but-not-in-ipython/23641560#23641560)

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, and it works for me (Ipython with python3.6.9), I've attached the results and configuration below.

Did you try to run it in a different [python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) (outside of Anaconda)?
As it has been stated before (in Ronald's comment) [other IDE's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914240/multiprocessing-pool-seems-to-work-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu) have bugs with python's multiprocessing, try run it using the command line/Ipython. I have previously encountered one even in [vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/9254)

#### Configuration:

[image: python configuration]

#### Results:

[image: script results]

Comment: thank you very much, I got it to work in win terminal... actually its windows thats messing everything up (once again...) 

unfortunately our lab PCs all run windows - I would prefer linux

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to make it work in Anaconda.

apart from the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

the function that is called (the worker) **has to be in its own .py file that has to be imported at the beginning..**

I put the RK4 in a RK4.py file that i imported at the beginning and not it works but that opens new problems in my case with passing the values back and forth...