# Python multiprocessing with pool and context manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am relatively new to Python and new to Python multiprocessing.  I am trying to execute a function repeatedly (10 times in the example below) as separate processes. Within the function I have a loop of multiple iterations (again, 10 times in the example below). In this example, and for simplicity, the function just sets a random number. Judging by the logging I've added, I have at least two problems. Firstly, while I see iteration 1 of each process instance starting and setting the random number, iteration 2 of each process instance starts but appears to do nothing beyond that and iterations 3-10 of each process don't appear to start at all. Secondly, there appears to be cross-contamination between process instances, with multiple processes apparently setting the same random number.

**My code**

```
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np

def do_it(n):
    for i in range(1,11):
        print("do_it instance" + " " + str(n) + ", iteration " + str(i) + " starting")
        try:
            rnd
        except NameError:
            print("do_it instance" + " " + str(n) + ", iteration " + str(i) + ": Variable is not defined")
        else:
            print("do_it instance" + " " + str(n) + ", iteration " + str(i)+ ": Variable is already defined as " + str(random))
        rnd = np.random.randint(1,1000)
        print("do_it instance" + " " + str(n) + ", iteration " + str(i) + ": rnd set to " + str(rnd))
        return rnd
def main():

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(do_it, range(1,11))
    print(results)
```

My aim is to end up with a list of 100 random numbers, one from each of the 10 process instances and 10 iterations therein. There's undoubtedly a simple explanation and solution to this but searching online for answers has not helped me. Are there any Python experts who can help?

**Log**

```
do_it instance 1, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 1, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 2, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 2, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 3, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 3, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 1, iteration 1: rnd set to 807
do_it instance 1, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 2, iteration 1: rnd set to 807
do_it instance 2, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 3, iteration 1: rnd set to 807
do_it instance 3, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 4, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 4, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 4, iteration 1: rnd set to 666
do_it instance 4, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 5, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 5, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 5, iteration 1: rnd set to 666
do_it instance 5, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 6, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 6, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 6, iteration 1: rnd set to 807
do_it instance 6, iteration 2 starting
do_it instance 7, iteration 1 starting
do_it instance 8, iteration 1 startingdo_it instance 7, iteration 1: Variable is not defined

do_it instance 8, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 8, iteration 1: rnd set to 666
do_it instance 8, iteration 2 startingdo_it instance 7, iteration 1: rnd set to 666

do_it instance 9, iteration 1 startingdo_it instance 7, iteration 2 starting

do_it instance 9, iteration 1: Variable is not defined
do_it instance 10, iteration 1 startingdo_it instance 9, iteration 1: rnd set to 947

do_it instance 9, iteration 2 startingdo_it instance 10, iteration 1: Variable is not defined

do_it instance 10, iteration 1: rnd set to 947
do_it instance 10, iteration 2 starting
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `there appears to be cross-contamination between process instances, with multiple processes apparently setting the same random number.` - why do you think the processes are *communicating* with each other? I don't see any place where you provided for that.

Comment: `My aim is to end up with a list of 100 random numbers,` - It doesn't look like you tried to implement that.

Comment: It's these lines in the log. Sorry, no idea why they don't format properly.  Three processes apparently setting the same random number.

do_it instance 1, iteration 1: rnd set to 807

do_it instance 2, iteration 1: rnd set to 807

do_it instance 3, iteration 1: rnd set to 807

Comment: My code is intended spawn 10 processes, each of which will create 10 random numbers. It appears to be spawning processes and each process is going through the loop, apparently twice.

Comment: Unless you seed the generator the separate processes should not be producing **exactly the same** series of numbers. It is possible that there will be repeats/duplicates. After fixing minor issues; a NameError, the indentation of the return statement, and/or accumulating the generated numbers before returning - the example you provided does not produce *identical* results from the separate processes. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: May I ask what version of Python you are using?  I am on 3.8 and there appears to have been changes in this release relating to shared memory (some of which is a bit beyond me).

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#multiprocessing

Is it possible that Numpy is now defaulting to using shared memory where in previous Python versions it did not?  If so, is there any way I can switch this behaviour off so that each process uses its own memory space?

Comment: The code that you provided previously which has since been removed from this page perfectly illustrates the problem when I run it. No duplicated lists of 10 numbers for the lists generated by Python's random function, several duplicates for the Numpy-generated lists.

Comment: I deleted that answer because it **does NOT** produce duplicate random lists from separate processes whether using numpy or python random generators- so it did not solve your problem or even replicate your problem. That is why it was deleted and I voted to close because I could not replicate your problem.

Comment: It replicated precisely my problem when I ran it.  There is a difference in our results.

Comment: Running the same code here also produces dupes:

https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter

Comment: There are caveats in the documentation regarding running multiprocessing stuff in an interactive shell/interpreter. Make sure `main` is called in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` suite then run it from a shell prompt - `python -m tmp` or `py -m tmp`. Look through search results for `python multiprocessing interactive site:stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I get the same when I run it from a shell prompt.

Comment: [Same output in different workers in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915177/same-output-in-different-workers-in-multiprocessing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914240/multiprocessing-pool-seems-to-work-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu,

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9650

Comment: Superb.  Adding "np.random.seed()" has fixed it.  Thanks for your help with this.