# Pool.map() results are different from just for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a function, let's call it `randomized()`. I need to run it on a list of identical odjects `items`.

When I run this with a simple for loop, like this

```py
results = []
for item in items:
    results.append(randomized(item))
```

then the `results` contains a list of elements, which are different from each other as the function `randomozed()` is non-deterministic.

However, when I want to run this in parallel, like this:

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = pool.map(randomized, items)
```

then the `results` list contains identical objects most of the time. Only rarely it contains just a single one which differs from others.

Why is the difference?

Comment: I added a `numpy.random.seed()` in the `randomized()` function, however it seems that still many of the result items are identical, even though it improved a bit...

Comment: as pointed out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914240/multiprocessing-pool-seems-to-work-in-windows-but-not-in-ubuntu

it seems that "on Unix every worker process inherits the same state of the random number generator from the parent process"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to initialize each process in the pool so that the random number generator is seeded with a unique seed. This is achieved by using the *initializer* argument of the `Pool` constructor.

The first demo uses the *same* seed for each process in the pool and shows that all processes will be returning the same random numbers (**this is *not* what you want because each process in the pool is staring off with a random number generator that is in the same identical initial state**):

```python
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

def init_pool():
    np.random.seed(1)

def worker(i):
    # ensure each process in the pool processes one request each:
    time.sleep(1)
    return multiprocessing.current_process().pid, np.random.random()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8, initializer=init_pool)
    results = pool.map(worker, range(8))
    for pid, number in results:
        print(f'pid={pid}, random number={number}')
```

Prints:

```
pid=46512, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=3444, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=13716, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=10800, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=47360, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=49932, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=51144, random number=0.417022004702574
pid=27360, random number=0.417022004702574
```

Note that on Linux/Unix the state of the random number generator would be inherited by all processes in the pool and thus they would automatically have the same initial identical state even without specifying a pool-initializer function as in the above code, which *is*, however, required for a platform such as Windows that uses `spawn` to create new processes.

The next demo initialized each process's random number generator with the current process' pid value (**this *is* what you want since it guarantees that each processor in the pool starts off with a random number generator initialized with its own unique state**):

```python
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

def init_pool():
    np.random.seed(multiprocessing.current_process().pid)

def worker(i):
    # ensure each process in the pool processes one request each:
    time.sleep(1)
    return multiprocessing.current_process().pid, np.random.random()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8, initializer=init_pool)
    results = pool.map(worker, range(8))
    for pid, number in results:
        print(f'pid={pid}, random number={number}')
```

Prints:

```
pid=19460, random number=0.5645643493822622
pid=23612, random number=0.5480593060571878
pid=28288, random number=0.2637370242174355
pid=6440, random number=0.6107958535345932
pid=24452, random number=0.6173634654672119
pid=1716, random number=0.2570898341750626
pid=14912, random number=0.11239641110464715
pid=49184, random number=0.34255660011034006
```

Comment: yes, this is somehow close to my comments for my own question :) Thank you for details!